# Is there a way to create custom URLs in WordPress for each client

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a site for a client who want's to use the WP Workscout theme. He want's a client portal that's able to do 2 things;

1. The clients logo and basic chosen style in their portal area
2. A url for the client for example clientname.companyname.com

I could do this quite simply with a custom site but I'm not sure about WordPress. Is it possible? If so, how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider building a WordPress multisite. Sounds like it might be what you're looking for.

It will allow you to have some different styling for each site in the network, and you can set up each site on different subdomains.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/

https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/

Comment: Thanks for this. Really helped a lot.